# Get physical path of network share in DOS or Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, dos

Simple question but I can't seem to find or figure out the answer.

I have a variable which indicates a windows network share, e.g.

```
\\myBoxName\networkshare\shared
```

Within either DOS or powershell (preferably the former, although it's not a big deal) I need to get another variable value that indicates the physical path of that network share. So the answer I'm looking for is something like ...

```
D:\Networkshare\shared
```

The script is running on the box on which the share is located, if that helps.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -filter "Name LIKE 'shared'").path # return the path of the share named 'shared"
```

Comment: (Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -filter "Name LIKE '\\BoxName\myShare'").path returns an "Invalid Query" error at character 15 - am I being an idiot with the syntax?

Comment: try (Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -filter "Name LIKE 'myShare'").path or (Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -filter "Name = 'myShare'").path

Comment: Aha, I see. I'll need to do a bit of string dissecting then, but it'll do what I need it to. Thanks!